# Send file to a browser using python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, http, web, server

I am trying to send a file(mp3) to a client(browser: Chrome) using python (only socket programming). My problem is that the file is getting downloaded instead of streaming on the browser. I am not able to understand where I am wrong. Please let me know.

Also, the audio file that gets downloaded is not corrupted and I am able to play the audio.

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import os
import time
from encodings.base64_codec import base64_encode
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port=8000

def createServer():

   serversocket.bind(("",port))
   serversocket.listen(5)
   file=open('music.mp3',"rb")
   z=file.read()
   var=len(z)
   file.close()
   (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
   clcommand=clientsocket.recv(1024).decode('utf8')

   header="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
   header1="Content-Type: audio/mpeg"
   header2="Content-Length: {}".format(var)
   blank="\r\n"

   sendt=header+header1+header2+blank
   clientsocket.send(sendt.encode())

   file=open("music.mp3",'rb')
   z=file.read(512)
   while (z):
     try:

        clientsocket.send(z)
        z=file.read(512)

     except:
        print("done sending")
        exit()

createServer()
```

Comment: What do you by displaying the audio file on the browser?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I meant play the audio file on the browser and I am using Chrome.

Comment: `sendt=header+header1+header2+blank` ... the header lines also need `\r\n` separators - including the last one so there is a `\r\n\r\n` before content.

Comment: As an aside, you can get the file size without reading it: `os.stat('music.mp3').st_size`.

Comment: `header="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"`
   `header1="Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n"`
   `header2="Content-Length: {}\r\n".format(var)`
    `blank="\r\n"`    . I changed to this. Its not downloading anymore but, its not streaming either.

Comment: I ran your code (with the fix) on my linux machine using chromium browser and I am rocking to the tune now (... it worked!).

Comment: That's strange. I am not able to play the music at all. Tried with IE also. Not working..

Comment: You have an `except` that catches and suppresses all errors. Do `except Exception as e:` and then `print(e)` and you may get more information.

Comment: Also, use `sendall` instead of `send` because `send` is not guaranteed to send everything you ask it to. Also, you could write a little python script that does the client GET instead of the browser to see what you get.

Comment: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.  This is the error i'm getting.

Comment: My connection keeps closing. Any idea why? handling the exception is fine but why do I even have that issue?